# Navbar showing in front of popup on Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having this issue (shown in the image) with the Twitter Bootstrap navbar and the slideshow from VisualLightBox.com.

This is the code for my navbar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       [...]
    </ul>
</div>
```

The html for the slideshow is very simple:

```
<div id="vlightbox1">
   [...]
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#vlightbox1 {
    width:50%;
    zoom:1; 
}
#vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:3px;
    width:160px;
    font-family:Trebuchet,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0.87;
    outline:none;
}
#vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 a{
    margin:0;
}
#vlightbox1 .vlightbox1:hover, #vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    opacity:1;
}
#vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 img{
    display:block;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
}
#vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 div {display:none}
```

I have tried giving a z-index of 10000 to the slideshow container with no luck. Am I missing something?

Thank you so much!

[image: Slideshow hidden behind navbar]

Comment: you need to show us the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar most likely has a higher z-index than the lightbox. Increase the z-index on the lightbox to see if it fixes your problem.

For example:

```
#vlightbox1 {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: He told that he "have tried giving a z-index of 10000 to the slideshow container with no luck."

Comment: Oops, missed that part! ;)